# To find the approximate solution of the series for large N

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

to make sum of series including combinations
${N\choose 1}{N\choose 0}+{N \choose 2}{N\choose 1}a^2 b^{-2} + {N\choose 3}{N \choose 2}a^4  b^{-4}+{N\choose 4}{N \choose 3}a^6 b^{-6}+...$Is it possible to sum the given series assuming $N$ is very large

${N\choose 1}$- denotes combination taking $1$ out of $N$. 
a and b are less than $1$ and $b=1-a$

Comment: Maple gives the sum of this series as n*hypergeom([-n, -n+1], [2], x), where $x$ is $(a/b)^2$. So, to sum this series you'll have to be more clever than Maple.